# Remove baseboard from small closet

Tags: baseboard

I am preparing to remove baseboard trim from a small closet and I am wondering which strategy I should follow, given:

1. the pieces closer to the door trim (baseboard cut at 90 degrees, let's call them pieces 1 and 5) are too small to use a trim puller (smaller than 2 inches each).
2. the other 3 pieces (2, 3, 4) have 45-degree mitered corners, and when I try to pry them, it feels like they press against each other making it harder to pry.

I thought about cutting a part of piece 2 out with an oscillating tool (it is gonna be cut anyway to fit a custom closet), but I am a bit anxious to screw up.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Remove the small pieces, then the others will come out easier.  Most baseboard is not attached as well as structural pieces and should pop off with screwdriver/prybar/hammer, anything you can get behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many times when trying to salvage small pieces of trim, the kind that would be found inside closets, something gets damaged. All that can be done is to use techniques to minimize the possibility.

First tip is to use a razor knife, or box cutter some know it by, and score all the areas that the base meet the walls, as well as the inside corners. This is where caulk is usually applied to hide gaps where the base meet other surfaces or each other. Done properly, this will release the hold that the caulk and paint will have on the base.

Whenever I am faced with the task of salvaging base, usually in a larger room, the base at either side of a door is where I always start. Corners could be mitered or coped, but there is always a square cut at the place where the base meets the door trim. If it is a coped piece, it could come out fairly easy. If it is mitered, it will break up pretty easily if not done right. The best way begin removal is to get the prybar worked under the bottom edge of the base and try to raise the base straight up, over riding the hold the nails have. This method will work if it is mitered or coped. Usually in small pieces like these, there may only be 1 or 2 nails holding it in. As a note, if these were long pieces, they could be bowed out from the center and release the ends, but with a small room like a closet, you will not have that option.

Once you get the pieces out by the door, you may find the rest is easy. Do not let yourself get fooled by prying against the drywall. It is a sure way to put dents or holes in your walls.

Last tip... If you successfully get all the base out, pull the nails out of the base by using pliers to pull the nails the rest of the way through from the back side. This will leave the face side clean with not blow outs from backing the nails out through the face of the trim.

Comment: This has the added advantage that if you break a piece of trim when removing it, it's most likely going to be the first piece you pull since it's the one wedged it at both edges. In this case, the 2" piece by the door will be the first piece and, if it breaks, you've only got to replace a 2" piece of trim on the back side of the inside of a closet door where _nobody_ will see it (until it needs to be replaced again). Therefore, if the replacement doesn't go all that well, nobody will notice.

Comment: Thanks, I actually followed the comment in the question, and started prying by the door, and got it all out. It took a lot of wiggling in the first piece, but I didn't damage anything (I added a backing board every time I pried). Everything else came off pretty easily. I think this answer is still super useful, so I'll accept it.

Comment: Trying to guess how it will go is nothing like being there. I'm glad it went easy for you, sometimes things go really well.